# Get Status Changes for Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use the GET envelopes API, and specifying a folder.  My folder_ids parameter is below:

&folder_ids='Sent Items'

I have also tried 'completed' and 'sent_items', but I get the same error:

"message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. folder_ids must be a comma separated list of either valid folder Guids or 'awaiting_my_signature', 'completed', 'draft', 'drafts', 'expiring_soon', 'inbox', 'out_for_signature', 'recyclebin', 'sentitems' or 'waiting_for_others'."

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong for my filter?

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a folderId it needs to be in a GUID format, unfortunately you cannot request envelopes based on the name of the folder.

The good news is that if you're looking for sent items there's another parameter you can use that is a bit more universal:

envelopes?from_date=8-1-2021&to_date=9-3-2021&folder_types=sentitems

I also tested folder_ids and it looks like the value for the sentitems folder os 'sentitems' there as well. You may want to consider opening a case with us to go over the process in realtime at https://support.docusign.com.

Regards,

Matt